Is there a UMP test of $H_0: \theta \le \theta_0$ vs $H_1: \theta > \theta_0$
Let $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$  be a random sample from a distribution with the density function:
$$ fθ(y)=\dfrac{3\theta^3}{y^4}  \text{ for } y \ge \theta  > 0$$
Is there a UMP test at level α for testing $H_0 : \theta \le \theta_0$ vs. $H_1 : \theta > \theta_0$?
My initial thoughts are to look for an MLR, so the likelihood ratio is as such:
$$
    \dfrac{L(\theta_1; y)}{L(\theta_0; y)} = \left(\dfrac{\theta_1}{\theta_0}\right)^{3n}
$$
This is a non-decreasing function, but it isn't a function of a statistic as the $Y_i$'s cancel out, so there is no MLR. I get stuck after here, because if there is no MLR does that mean that there is definitely not a UMP test, or do I need to search for it another way?
Thank you!

Two things to think about: (a) what happens if some of the $y_i \le \theta_0$ and some $y_j>\theta_0$ ? (b) how does your "uniformly most powerful" definition handle equally powerful tests?
